# Tasks never complete when ContinueWhenAll and TaskCompletionSource

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to force load an async datasource but wait for it synchronously so it works with legacy code (Using .net4.0).

If I create several Tasks, in excess of 1000 with a TaskCompletionSource and comment out the ContinueWhenAll, eventually each task completes as expected asynchronously. However when I introduce ContinueWhenAll I'm only ever able to set the TaskCompletionSource on one task.

Is it possible to make the following wait until all TaskCompletionSource are set and then escape from the LoadAllRows method?

Any help would be appreciated,

Cheers

```
    public void LoadAllRows()
    {
        var allLoaded = false;

        var tasks = new List<Task<bool>>();
        for (var i = 0; i <= mDataRowCount; i++)
            tasks.Add(EnsureRowLoaded(mDataController, i));

        Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks.ToArray(), (antecendents) =>
        {
            //Check all loaded here
        }).Wait();
        if (!allLoaded)
        {
            //Throw some exception
        }
    }

    private Task<bool> EnsureRowLoaded(AsyncServerModeDataController dataController, int rowHandle)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        //Async method with callback setting the tcs result
        dataController.EnsureRowLoaded(rowHandle, o => tcs.SetResult(true));
        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

Comment: "I'm not able to" is not a very useful description, what does the code actually do?

Comment: My code is used to force load an entire async datasource and wait for its completion before exiting.